# For to select the value in specific number corresponding to row number

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, I have a df as below, I would like to calculate value at any row of col 2 = value at row+1 of col1 / value at that row of col 1. Illustration is below.

How to code the above idea and keep doing so till the end.PLease help.

```
Col1   Col2 
1      Value at row 2 of col1/ value at row 1 of col1?
2      Value at row 3 of col1/ value at row 2 of col1?
3   
4
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Lot of ways to do this.

Consider your dataframe as :

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5)
```

1. You can use `lead` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(col2 = lead(col1)/col1)

#  col1 col2
#1    1 2.00
#2    2 1.50
#3    3 1.33
#4    4 1.25
#5    5   NA
```

2. `shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, col2 := shift(col1, type = "lead")/col1]
```

3. In base R :

a. With `head` and `tail` :

```
transform(df, col2 = c(tail(col1, -1)/head(col1, -1), NA))
```

b. by indexing

```
transform(df, col2 = c(col1[-1]/col1[-nrow(df)], NA))
```

Comment: Please see My answer with an attached pic below

Comment: @WillN You need to assign the data back to the object `df <- df %>% mutate(col2 = lead(col1)/col1)`. BTW you should delete your answer since it is not actually an answer. That space is reserved only for answers, not for clarifications and explanations.